# PHP: Can't Get Oracle Table to Display on Page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, oracle

This is probably a really obvious error. Anyway, some details:

I have an oracle database that I need to extract data from to populate a table on a PHP page. The table is called Flowers and has Name, Price and Stock columns.

The part of the PHP code I'm having trouble with is this:

```
$titlevalue = Trim($_REQUEST['search']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM FLOWERS WHERE NAME = '$titlevalue'";

$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query); 
if(!$stmt) {
    echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n"; 
    exit; 
}
OCIExecute($stmt);
```

The rest of my PHP works -perfectly- when using a different table on my database, which I did as a test. Just in case, this is the code that prints the query results (it's part of an HTML table, but you can ignore that):

```
while(OCIFetch($stmt)) {
    echo "<tr valign=top bgcolor=#F7D4A3>";
    $fg1 = OCIResult($stmt,"NAME");
    echo "<td width=75>";
    echo $fg1;
    echo "</td>";
// Display values in column two.
    $fg2 = OCIResult($stmt,"PRICE");
    echo "<td width=75>";
    echo ($fg2);
    echo "</td>";
// Display values in column three
    $fg3 = OCIResult($stmt, "STOCK");
    echo "<td width=75>";
    include($fg3);
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

No matter what $titlevalue becomes, I just can't get results with this table. I have also tested it with a generic `$query = "SELECT * FROM FLOWERS";`, but that didn't produce anything either.

Could someone please lend a hand? :( It's been a very long night.

Comment: What is the actual value of your sql statement before it is submitted?  echo...What error do you receive?

Answer (score 0):

If I may, two things just to note:

1)     you're using '$titlevalue', i think that will translate as ... $titlevalue in the query, and not its value

2)     Its late ... have you checked that your table is called FLOWERS (case sensitivity)

I'd comment, but I dont have the rep to do so.

If this was helpful, please +1 or click the tickmark. I normally try and use the full format when doing sql queries

```
SELECT * FROM `table name` WHERE 'x'
```

... etc. where possible